# How to optimize viewrenderable in arcore?

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform, android-augmented-reality

I created an application that use viewrenderable to show Gif in ARCore, but after 90-100 or more the app will crash. How to reuse viewrenderable in ARCore?

```
       ViewRenderable.builder()
            .setView(fragment.context, gifObject)
            .build()
            .thenAccept { viewRenderable ->
                viewRenderable.view
                ... //create anchor and node
            }
```

Please help me, I'm using ARCore Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you create too many anchors,It's very resource intensive,you could create an anchor,an anchorNode as global,then every frame,you detach last anchor,then create a new anchor,and use anchorNode.setAnchor(anchor). have a try,maybe it works.

Comment: I tried to remove all anchor in session but it's not working and I tried to reuse viewrenderable too. It helps a bit, but it just postponed the crash

Answer (score 0):

Incase you haven't found a solution yet, I recommend debugging and find out any rendering related issues using [Graphics API Debugger](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/android/gapid) (GAPID). It comes with an interface that lets you  view and inspect frame by frame